# Loops not incrementing correctly in C

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

Hello I'm new to C i'm using c99 to compile and I'm just making a program that prints different shapes using a *.

I'm having an issue making a diagonal line here is the code I'm using a while loop with a nested for loop inside of a switch statement.

If I tell it that there will be 5 * I get 3 in return and if I give it the number 7 I get 4. The spacing works correctly but it isn't finishing out the loop.

Any help would be great!

```
case 'd':
    printf("Size: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    index =0;
    while (index<=num){
// makes spaces
    for (int i=0; i<num-1; i++){
            printf(" ");
    }
    printf("*");
    printf("\n");
    num--;
    index++;
    }             
    break;
```

input 
Size: 5
output:
    *
   *
  *

Comment: Enable all warnings and debug info (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Note that you don't need to both `index++` and `num--`, I guess `index++` is enough.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Might be more fun using befunge?

Comment: I'm using c99 -Wall it doesn't say there are any errors

Comment: -Wall and other -W flags show the **warnings**, not errors. They're different

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.. shoud draw diagonal for you.

Changes:

> 1. `while (index<num){` `While` condition edited.
> 2. `for (int i=index-1; i >= 0; i--)` `for` edited from index to 0.
> 3. num--; not required.

```
while (index<num){
        // makes spaces
        for (int i=index-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
        printf("\n");
        //num--;
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: this works but the stars are printing in the opposite direction

Comment: change for to _for (int i=(num-index-1); i >= 0; i--)_

Comment: @user3400512 But can't you think, what is to be done for print in reverse ;)